# VirtualBoxについて

Tags: linux, virtualbox

ここ最近、とりあえずVirtualBoxを使って仮想環境でLinuxを楽しんでいる初心者です。

そこて、VirtualBox内では2つのLinuxディストリビューションを導入しており、それぞれメモリに8GB確保、ストレージに40GBすつ確保している状態です。

ホストOSのスペックとしては16GBメモリ、ストレージは512GBで、割と悪くないスペックかと思われるのですが、例えば、現在の私の使用状況ではホストOS側に少し負担がかかる状況だと思われますか（特にメモリの部分）？単一ならまだしも、2つ同時起動は怖くてやっていません。

「いや、インストールした複数のOSの同時起動させることさえなければ、何台入れようが単独起動でサクサク動けば全然問題ないんじゃない」とか、実際はそういうものなんでしょうか？

何卒ご教授くださいますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

ゲスト OS のメモリは、実行時にホストのメモリを使用します。
停止させれば、開放されます。

ゲスト OS のストレージは、実行していなくてもホストのストレージを使用します。
Virtual Box のドライブ作成時に、可変サイズを指定していれば、利用した分のストレージが確保されます。
一度増えると、自動で小さくなることはありません。

メモリ使用率が 90% を越えるくらいになると、メモリ不足でゲスト OS が停止させられることがありますので、様子を見ながら調整すると良いでしょう。

自分が耐えられる速度ならば、複数起動でも問題ありません。

Answer (score 0):

「Linuxを楽しんでいる」方なら、ホストがさくさく動いているうちは、ゲストを２台同時に立ち上げても問題ないと思います。ただし、ホストが使う分は残しておいた方がよいと思います。※ゲストを１台づつ動かすなら、ホストの分が8Gありますので、それならば問題ないと思います。

私のプライベートなPCはメモリ16Gです。ホストの分を8G残して、ゲスト2台を4Gづつ割り当て、ゲストを2台とも立ち上げて遊んでいます。

仕事で使っているPCはメモリ8Gなので、ゲストは4Gにしています。何台かゲストを作っていますが、同時に立ち上げるゲストは1台だけです。※落ちるのが怖いためです。

Answer (score 0):

- 実PCと同じように、(ゲストOSに)割り当てたメモリが常にすべて利用されるわけではありません。
- 「ゲストOS」もホストOSから見れば他のアプリと同様にプロセスの一つに過ぎないので、リソースが許す限り同時起動はもちろん可能です。
- 「何台入れようが単体起動すれば」は概ねその通りです。私は32bit = メモリ4GB のPCでも、ゲストOSを10個程度作成しています (起動するのは1つずつ)。
- 実際にはホストOSのメモリだけではなく、ストレージへのアクセス速度も重要になってきます。

---

なお、VirtualBoxでゲストOSの設定からメモリの割り当て量を変更できますが、(ホストOSの)実メモリの半分程度を割り当てようとすると警告が表示されるはずなので、この辺りも参考にするとよいでしょう。